# Copy of Terminal app is removed after each restart

Tags: terminal, rosetta-2

I'm using a M1 Mac Mini and have created a duplicate of the Terminal app called "Rosetta Terminal" that runs Rosetta.

Each time I restart/update my computer this duplicate is removed from the Applications folder. Why? How can I keep it?

Also, when I create a duplicate of the regular non-rosetta terminal and rename it to "Rosetta Terminal" it somehow remembers/knows that it should open in Rosetta mode. Super weird.

Comment: Is this a personal Mac Mini? - Or is it managed by a employer or educational institution? - In general, it should definitely not happen that applications are automatically removed. Some third party thing has been introduced that does first - for example a computer managed by an employer could have been setup to do this on boot.

Comment: It's my own personal computer. Not managed in any way.

Comment: Can't explain that, either, but what happens if you put the duplicate in ~/Applications? (i.e. in the user account.)

Comment: Might be a good idea. I'll try. But it doesn't seem to appear in Spotlight search then.

Comment: A slightly different issue I have after upgrading to Monterey 12.5, my rosetta terminal duplicate I made previously is now gone. Unfortunately now, although I can still create a duplicate of Terminal.app, I can't rename it and neither I can change the icon to recognise which is what. Somehow they locked the ability of editing the app name and icon and I can't find how to do that.

Other than that, the duplicate that is set to open with rosetta, operates properly.